# Convert python list to HTML table

Tags: python, html

I am a novice coder and am not able to figure out my mistake here...
I have a text that looks like this:

```
AAA,48,48,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
BBB,30,24,6,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

I want to write it to a HTML table. The code for that is this:

```
temp_lines=ftemp.readlines();
for line in temp_lines:
        tl,total,counter_pass,counter_kbug,counter_ubug,totbug,counter_kscr,counter_uscr,totscr,counter_kset,counter_uset,totset=line.split(",");

f.write("<tr><td height=\"30\"><a href="something".html>"+str(t1)+"</a></td><td height=\"30\">"+str(total)+"</a></td><td height=\"30\">"+str(counter_pass)+"</td><td height=\"30\">"+str(counter_kbug)+"</td><td>"+str(counter_ubug)+"</td><td height=\"30\">"+str(totbug)+"</td><td height=\"30\">"+str(counter_kscr)+"</td><td height=\"30\">"+str(counter_uscr)+"</td><td height=\"30\">"+str(totscr)+"</td><td height=\"30\">"+str(counter_kset)+"</td><td height=\"30\">"+str(counter_uset)+"</td><td height=\"30\">"+str(totset)+"</td></tr></center><br>");
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

I am explicitely converting every list object to string. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `item[4:]` is a `list`, as you are using [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation). You might want `item[4]`, I don't know.

Comment: the error message explains itself, have you tried debugging?  what have you attempted to remedy this? <td height=\"30\"><a href="something".html>"+str(t1)----->  try messing around with this and consider reading a bit on list manipulations http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/python-list-manipulation

Comment: @Peter Wood, That didnt fix my issue! :/

Comment: Your example isn't valid as you don't escape all your quotes: `"<tr><td height=\"30\"><a href="something`

Answer (score 0):

Consider the [following](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html):

```
For example, ' 1  2   3  '.split() returns ['1', '2', '3']
```

you are trying to do this str(['1', '2', '3'])

what happens when you try and concatenate:

```
"some html" + str(['1', '2', '3'])"
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

consider reading [list manipulation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) or viewing a tutorial on [this](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/python-list-manipulation):

bascically, you need to extract the data from the list:

```
var_to_html = List_name[0] #position of the element to extract from the list
 now you can do "html" + var_to_html
```